# How to access UIButton in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview

I'd like to selectively enable the 'save' button on my UIAlertView so that you can't save a file with no name. I can listen to text changed events for the attached UITextView (the style is UIAlertViewStylePlainText), but I can't see how to access the buttons so that I can do the enable/disable. I've tried iterating through [alertView subviews], but there is only the label in there (no buttons). Where do I need to look to directly access the UIButtons attached to a UIAlertView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple, just implement the UIAlertViewDelegate in your class and utilize the `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` delegate method. You can use this to check the length of the text field, and enable the button accordingly...

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    return [[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] length] > 0;
}
```

Make sure you set your view controller to conform to this delegate in your interface using `< UIAlertViewDelegate >` and to set this class as the alerts delegate upon instantiation.

Comment: I'll just check this - but I suspect this is the right answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate your alertview:

```
UIAlertView *av = [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"my title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
    });
```

Then make sure your class implements UIAlertViewDelegate, and look for the button index of the button you want to listen to:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex==1) {
        //save here
    }
}
```

Comment: James wants to enable/disable the button programatically, not do something when the button is clicked.

Comment: that won't work - I need the UIButton in order to selectively disable it.

Comment: Custom class might be the way to go in that case.  I don't think iterating through the UIViews of UIAlertView will help your code be future-proof, among other things that could be hazardous...

Comment: @00x7fffffff's answer above seems to do what you need.

Comment: I want to detect if the textfield on alertview is empty, the Save button should be disable. how can I do???

Answer (score 0):

0x7fffffff posted right answer, but if someone is looking for answer how to add that textfield and save button to UIAlertView, here is the answer:

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
    [alert setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
```

---

This delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    return [[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] length] > 0;
}
```

won't work if you add that save button with `addButtonWithTitle:` method.

---

And when save button is clicked, this delegate method is called and here you can read what user wrote to that text field:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(buttonIndex == 1) {
       // Save button clicked
       NSLog(@"%@", [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't access the buttons of an alert view as of iOS 7. Unfortunately they made the subviews completely hidden and there's no way to access them.

Comment: This is true but thankfully the `UIAlertViewDelegate` provides the proper solution to the problem.

Comment: I've had issue with using that method. Hopefully the questioner will have more luck than me.